# Implement an asynchronous tcp connection with a timeout

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am getting an exception:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in 
 System.dll

 Additional information: This protocol version is not supported."
```

when I run the following code. I am trying to implement an asynchronous tcp connection with a timeout.

I've seen and read several stack overflow examples, some using TcpClient and some using Socket. I assume the former wraps up the latter and is newer. I am trying with TcpClient.BeginConnect

The documentation does not list NotSupported as one of the exception types this method can throw. How do I track down what the problem is?

```
public class Client
{
    private string m_host;
    private uint m_port;
    private uint m_timeoutMilliseconds;
    private TcpClient m_client;

    public Client(string host, uint port, uint timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        m_host = host;
        m_port = port;
        m_timeoutMilliseconds = timeoutMilliseconds;
        m_client = new TcpClient();
    }

    public bool Connect()
    {
        IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(m_host);
        IPAddress ipAddress = hostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, (int)m_port);

        IAsyncResult result = m_client.BeginConnect(ipAddress, (int)m_port, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), m_client);
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne((int)m_timeoutMilliseconds, true);

        // SNIP

        return true;
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MakeRequest(string symbol)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    private static void OnConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}"
                        , socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Integration.Client("127.0.0.1", 24001, 360000);
        client.Connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What OS are you running the code on?  NotSupported is often related to OS or OS configuration, although I'm not sure that's the case here.

Comment: Server 2012 R2 Standard with .Net 4.5

Comment: Just print somehow the whole exception you are getting, and not only its Message property. as example, wrap the code in Main within a try/catch:     `static void Main(string[] args)
    {
try{
        Client client = new Integration.Client("127.0.0.1", 24001, 360000);
        client.Connect();
    }
}
catch (Exception exc){System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString());}`

Comment: Ah, you may want to check out your `hostinfo.AddressList` a bit more.  Possibly you are ending up with an IPv6 address (or some other unsupported protcol on the current machine.)  In other words, `ipAddress` may be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it is giving me an ip v6 address. But why wouldn't that be supported in 2017? It is enabled on the network adapter matching the ipv6 address it is getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `TcpClient` assumes you're using an IPv4 address. There's a [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky8sayff(v=vs.110).aspx) that lets you specify which address family to use though, but this would mean constructing it after you've done the dns lookup:

```
m_client = new TcpClient(ipAddress.AddressFamily);
IAsyncResult result = m_client.BeginConnect(ipAddress, (int)m_port, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), m_client);
```

Alternatively you could find the IPv4 address in the `hostInfo.AddressList` and connect to that - that's what the [`BeginConnect(string host, ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xw3y33he(v=vs.110).aspx) overload does for you under the hood (unless you have specified IPv6 in the constructor).

I have no idea why they didn't just take the `AddressFamily` from the `IPAddress` you're passing, perhaps because the underlying `Socket` is created in the `TcpClient` constructor. I was also suprised to see the following in the [reference source page](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,943f9db3a7511918) of `TcpClient`:

```
//
// IPv6: Maintain address family for the client
//
AddressFamily m_Family = AddressFamily.InterNetwork;
```

I don't understand that comment, but apparently someone did have IPv6 in mind when choosing the default.

Comment: Interesting, because yeah, if you pass a hostname to BeginConnect, it picks IPv6 (according to the docs anyway)

Comment: On my machine with that overload, it picks the address family I specify in the constructor, or IPv4 when using the default constructor. The `myTcpClient.Client.AddressFamily` is also set to that value even before connecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only after an IP4 local address try this

```
using System.Linq;

IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(m_host).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsIPv6LinkLocal == false);
```

I just tried your example and had the same error, with the above it seemed to work.